# Why can't I make this (SectionsPagerAdapter) class private?

Tags: java, android, class

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

I am doing a Head First Android tutorial and I cannot make this class private? Is there a different way to do this on android? Should I add parameters for the super class?

Comment: Is this class held within another class? AFAIK that's the only use case for making a class private, else they must be package-private at minimum.

Comment: Besides what M.Warren says, I am curious why you need the class to be private? Maybe you want it to be final instead?

Answer (score 1):

Classes that are self-contained within their own file cannot be declared `private` as they cannot be accessed by any other class, effectively rendering them useless. The only time a class can be declared `private` is if it is a child of another class e.g.

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB myInstance = new ClassB();

    private class ClassB {
        public ClassB() {}
    }
}
```

In this case, `ClassB` is only visible to `ClassA`, and can only be used by `ClassA`. If your class is self-contained in its own file, the maximum privacy it can have is `package-private` i.e. no specifier:

```
package com.example.myPackage;

class ClassB {
    ClassB() { }
}
```

In this case, `ClassB` can only be accessed and instantiated by any other class contained within the `com.example.myPackage` package.